# How can I make an iframe grow/shrink with the browser window, when surrounded by fixed content?

Tags: html, css, iframe

Consider the following code:

```
<html>
<head>
<style>
html {height:100%;}
body {margin:0;}
iframe {height:100%;border:1px dotted red;}

.hdr {min-width:765px}
.logo_left {margin:4px}
.logo_right {float:right;margin:4px}
.menu {float:left;width:175px}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<div class="hdr">
    <img class="logo_left" src="img.png">
    <img class="logo_right" src="img2.png">
 </div>
<iframe class="menu" src="/menu.shtm"></iframe>
<iframe class="content" src="/home.htm"></iframe>
</body>
</html>
```

From the above code, I have a header that has a minimum width and can grow as the browser window grows or shrinks in width.  Underneath the header, I have a fixed width `iframe` that can grow in height, but is fixed on the left and immediately under the header.

My problem is with the content `iframe` element.  What I need is for the top and left edges to be fixed in place and the right and bottom edges to grow and shrink with the browser.  I can't find a way to do this.

I've read through numerous questions with good answers on here and many of them tend to work with `div` tags.  Is there a way that I can get my content `iframe` to layout the way I desire, strictly using CSS and HTML attributes.  In my case, I can't use JavaScript, so that isn't an option.

Also, I'd prefer to stay away from setting width and the height of the `iframe` to a percentage.  The existence of the header and the left-hand menu throw off the positioning.  If there is away around this limitation, I am open to suggestions.

As you can see from the code, I am setting the height of both `iframe` elements to 100%.  This means that these `iframe` elements always size beyond the lower bounds of the browser, equal to the height of my header.  This is an annoyance but I can live with it.  What I really need is to fix the edges of my content `iframe` to the corresponding edges of the header, menu and browser window.  Can this be done?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could wrap divs around your iframes and absolutely position those divs to the bottom, top and sides that you need.

Like so: 
http://jsfiddle.net/wKHVz/

```
<html>
    <head>
        <style>
            html {height:100%;}
            body {margin:0; min-height: 100%; position: relative;}
            .menuIframe, .contentIframe {width: 100%; height: 100%; border: none; }
            .menuIframe {background: #ff9999; }
            .contentIframe {background: #99ff99; }

            .logo_left {float: left; margin:4px}
            .logo_right {float:right; margin:4px}
            .menu {position: absolute; top: 50px; left: 0px; bottom: 0px; width:175px}
            .content {position: absolute; top: 50px; left: 175px; bottom: 0px; right: 0px;}
        </style>
    </head>

    <body>
        <div class="hdr">
            <img class="logo_left" src="img.png">
            <img class="logo_right" src="img2.png">
         </div>
        <div class="menu"><iframe class="menuIframe" src="/menu.shtm"></iframe></div>
        <div class="content"><iframe class="contentIframe" src="/home.htm"></iframe></div>
    </body>
</html>​​​​​​​​​​
```

In this example I have given 50px room for your header, but you could change this to whatever size header you need. Just change the top value of both of the iframes.

Answer (score 0):

Pop the iframe into a wrapper that is position:relative;

Comment: mikefortuna: Please post some sample code. I know how to wrap it in a div. Simple enough. Should I set any other CSS properties on the iframe?

Comment: I've tried everything I can thing of to get this suggestion to work.  Please modify the above code, and post it as an example.